# Is there a difference between "punishment" and "discipline"?

Tags: word-study

In [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32541/what-is-the-biblical-basis-that-god-does-not-punish-disobedient-christians-beyon?noredirect=1#comment84747_32541) on Christianity.SE, I asked if there is Scriptural passages that support the idea that God does not punish those who are in Christ, in the sense of intervening to cause negative effects beyond the natural consequences of their actions for the purpose of justice and retribution.

We did arrive at some difficulty however, when we observed that some translations use "discipline", while others use "punishment", and between translations the words are often interchanged.

In the biblical texts, is there support for a notion of "punishment", eg. Jeremiah 9:9, Hebrews 10:29, an intervention for the purpose of retribution and penalty for unrighteousness, distinct from a notion of "discipline", eg. Deuteronomy 8:5, Hebrews 2:11, an intervention for the purpose of instruction in righteousness?

Comment: @PaulVargas I'm aware of that verse. Are both mentioned because they are the same? Or because they're different?

Comment: @Andrew - we really need a text to discuss here, not just the broad question in the abstract. Otherwise, your question is in danger of being closed as [not "on topic"](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: okay, let me grab a few references.

Comment: @Andrew [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) You'll need to justify quoting from both Hebrew Bible and NT texts and relating them like this (they are written in different languages and time periods), this is likely too broad for asking here as is. You seem to be starting from a theological idea and then asking us to find biblical support for it - which doesn't work here. You must start from a text and attempt to minimize your presuppositions when asking ideally. This question seems better for [Christianity.SE].

Comment: @Andrew I believe if you find a particular text to reference from, and stick with that, you can get your question answered. You will need to re-edit your question starting with the text, then asking is it means such. Otherwise CSE is probably your best option.